# Gnuplot & C++: Can't find gnuplot neither in PATH nor in "

Tags: c++, gnuplot

I am trying to use Gnuplot on Windows with gnuplot_i.hpp. When I type "gnuplot" into cmd everthing works, so the PATH variable should be set correctly. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gnuplot_i.hpp"
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    try {
        Gnuplot g1("lines");
    } catch (GnuplotException ge) {
        cout << ge.what() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is  Can't find gnuplot neither in PATH nor in "C:/program files/gnuplot/bin" .

When I add the line

```
Gnuplot::set_GNUPlotPath("C:/gnuplot/bin/");
```

it just changes to Can't find gnuplot neither in PATH nor in "".

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer myself: For some reason gnuplot_i.hpp expects your exe to be called pgnuplot.exe instead of gnuplot.exe ... Now everything works.

Comment: In the file 'gnuplot_i.hpp', change the variable value to refer to gnuplot.exe:- std::string Gnuplot::m_sGNUPlotFileName = "gnuplot.exe";